# Shooter FPS 3d UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with the position of the camera and weapon shot. If you check the photo, on the left is a red ray that is the real direction of the shot. But my weapon is not at the same position of the camera. When I apply the direction to shot, I have this issue and the yellow `LineRender` (right of the picture) hit the cube.

This problem is only occurs when the shot doesn't hit a gameObject

The black quad of screen is a Canvas to simulate the crosshair
[image: Picture]

[Full Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1710ha9F09q_A9S1-bjLJfpXLGUsImO1q/view?usp=sharing)

```cs
void Update() {
    line.SetPosition(0, posGun.position);
    Vector3 auxPos_ = cam.position + cam.forward * distance;
       
      
    if(Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        line.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
    }
    else
    {
        line.SetPosition(1, auxPos_);![alt text][2]
    }
 
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth/2f,Camera.main.pixelHeight/2f, 0));
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, Camera.main.transform.forward * 10, Color.red);
}
```

Comment: Ok. It’s not entirely clear however. Note. Your ray cast is say 1 pixel wide the shot beam in yellow is clearly not. It also seems to start from the end of the gun and that line extends to the right of the screen not the left where your red ray sat line seems to start.

Comment: The Yellow line start in Gun Position and go to  red ray direction.
Is just that.
But he effect is not ral because the "aim" picture" point out of cube and you hit cube

Comment: But the yellow line and red line don’t follow the same path hence it’s not surprising they get different results

Comment: @DanielRayos Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes...I did a tutorial to explain that..Just reduce the weapon

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGuK3lort9w&list=PLrjSxxUlyA1pvD-iCFf_f59uuIGP7Aehm&index=4

Answer (score 0):

Don't simply set the line to where the aiming raycast hits. First, do a 2nd raycast from the gun to where the aiming raycast hits. Then, if that hits anything, draw the line from the gun to that point instead.

```
void Update() {
    line.SetPosition(0, posGun.position);
    Vector3 auxPos_ = cam.position + cam.forward * distance;
       
      
    if(Physics.Raycast(cam.position, cam.forward, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        Vector3 fireDirection = hit - posGun.position;
        Vector3 hitFromGun;
        if (Physics.Raycast(posGun.position, fireDirection, out hitFromGun, Mathf.Infinity))
        {
            line.SetPosition(1, hitFromGun.point);
        }
        else 
        {
            line.SetPosition(1, hit.point);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        line.SetPosition(1, auxPos_);![alt text][2]
    }
 
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Camera.main.pixelWidth/2f,Camera.main.pixelHeight/2f, 0));
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, Camera.main.transform.forward * 10, Color.red);
}
```

Comment: It's a begin good idea
but no fix the problem.
Because the "aim cursor picture" is out of cube. But you with weapon hit cube then you shot to cube.
Because now The yellow raycast start in weapong position and go to red ray direction

because the problem is when I don't touch anything with ray. Then aren't in of the IF

Comment: Sorry I dont understand